# ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 13 to array axis with dimension 200

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

```
DataReader = pd.read_csv('Quality.csv')
...
ip = [DataReader.x1, DataReader.x2, DataReader.x3, DataReader.x4,........., DataReader.x12, 
DataReader.x13]
op = DataReader.y
ip = np.matrix(ip).transpose()
op = np.matrix(op).transpose()
```

Please help to solve below error. Python 3.7v and numpy 1.17v

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Quality.py", line xx, in <module>
ip = np.matrix(ip).transpose()
File "\\defmatrix.py", line 147, in __new__
arr = N.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
**ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 13 to array axis with dimension 200**
```

Comment: Tell us more about `DataReader` - rows, columns, dtypes

Comment: What does `DataReader.values` produce?  Array with what shape and dtype?

Comment: rows 200 and total columns are 14 (x=13 and y=1) and dtype - float64

Comment: ignore previously mentioned dtype.  dtypes are int64 and float 6

Comment: DataReader.values produce array with (200, 14) shape

Comment: is there any restriction on passing number of instances to ip? In my case its 13 (x1 to x13).

Answer (score 0):

You start with a dataframe with 200 rows and 14 columns.  Its `.values` attribute (or `to_numpy()` method result) will then be a (200,14) shape array.

In:

```
ip = [DataReader.x1, DataReader.x2, ...DataReader.x13]
```

`DataReader.x1` is a column, a pandas Series.  Its `.values` is a 1d array, (200,) shape.  I would expect `np.array(ip)` to be a (13,200) array.

If instead you'd done

```
ip.DataReader[['x1','x2',...,'x13']].values
```

the result would be a (200,13) array.

With a simple dataframe, your code shouldn't produce an error:

```
In [61]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['a','b','c'])  
In [63]: df.values                                                                      
Out[63]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In [65]: ip = [df.a, df.b, df.c]   
In [67]: np.array(ip)                                                                   
Out[67]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```

`np.matrix(ip).transpose()` works just as well (though there's no need to use `np.matrix` instead of `np.array`).

I can't reproduce your error.  Making an `array` from certain mixes of shaped arrays produces an error like

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (1)
```

or in other cases an object array (of Series).

====

For one column, I'd expect the resulting 1d array, or reshape if needed.

```
In [82]: df.a                                                                           
Out[82]: 
0    0
1    3
2    6
3    9
Name: a, dtype: int64
In [83]: df.a.values                                                                    
Out[83]: array([0, 3, 6, 9])
In [84]: df.a.values[:,None]                                                            
Out[84]: 
array([[0],
       [3],
       [6],
       [9]])
```